# How to filter records using multiselect dropdown value combinations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a multiselect dropdown that a user can select more than 1 item at a time.
Using this multiselect value I need to filter my datasource and return the parsed result to a gridview.
Here is my code . I have tried to explain it as much as I can. Please feel free to ask me any question. I have also added my code. I think I am there right about to solving this but maybe there is a better and easier way of doing this.
Thank you in advance

Expected Scenario and Result (return not null values as per Department selected)

**Given are the multi select Scenarios**

**Production - 1 , Shipping - 2 , Logisitics - 3 as per dropdown**

- Production ----> Return all not null value for ProductionError
- Logistics -----> Return all not null value for LogisticsError
- Shipping  -----> Return all not null value for ShippingError

**When MultiSelect combination**

- Production + Shipping -> Return all not null for ( ProductionError & Shipping)
- Production + Logistics-> Return all not null for ( ProductionError & LogisticsError)
- Shipping + Logistics i.e (not null for Shipping and Logisitcs)
- Shipping + Logisitics + Production (not null for Shipping & Logisitics & ProductionErrors)

**My code So far :)**

- Main method has the scenerio I defined above.
- farmerlist has the records we need to filter.
- If statement maybe that needs to be changed

```
 internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Lets say user selected 3 values in the multiselect
            string dropdownSeleted = "1,2,3";
            var result = new List<Farmers>();   

            foreach (string dropdownSeletedValue in dropdownSeleted.Split(','))
            {
                //check if the enum type matches 
                if (DropdownEnum.Production.ToString() == dropdownSeletedValue)     
                {
                    farmerList()
                    result =  farmerList().Where(x => x.ProductError != null).ToList();

                }

                //When user selects 2 
                if (DropdownEnum.Shipping.ToString() == dropdownSeletedValue)
                {

                    result =farmerList().Where(x => x.ShippingError != null).ToList();

                }

                //When user select 3 
                if (DropdownEnum.Logistics.ToString() == dropdownSeletedValue)
                {

                    result = farmerList().Where(x => x.ProductError != null).ToList();

                }
                

            }
            // The above approach is not working if we have multi select like below 
            //Need to do 

            //When user selects 1&2 i.e Production & Logistics             
            //When user selects 1&3 i.e Production & Logistics 
            // When user selects 2&3 i.e Shiping and Logistics 

            //when user select 1,2,3 
             result = farmerList().Where(x => x.ProductError != null).Where(x => x.ShippingError != null).Where(x => x.LogisticError != null).Select(x => x).ToList();  //returns Id = 1 which is right , maybe i can use this and add if to it 

            //Do I do this for each combinations or is there a better approach to doing this 
        }

        public static List<Farmers> farmerList()
        {
            string dropdownSeletedValue = "0,1"; // here the user selected 0- Production  1-Shipping 
            //Idea is to show the records for multiselected Items 

            List<Farmers> resultForDataSouuce = new List<Farmers>();
            List<Farmers> farmers = new List<Farmers> {new Farmers {ID = 1, Name = "Item1",  ProductError = 1 ,    ShippingError = 1 ,    LogisticError = 2},
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 2, Name = "Item2",  ProductError = null , ShippingError = 3,     LogisticError = 2},
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 3, Name = "Item3",  ProductError = null , ShippingError = null,  LogisticError = null },
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 4, Name = "Item4",  ProductError = null , ShippingError = null,  LogisticError = null },
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 5, Name = "Item5",  ProductError = 1 ,    ShippingError = null,  LogisticError = null },
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 6, Name = "Item6",  ProductError = 1 ,    ShippingError = null,  LogisticError = null },
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 7, Name = "Item7",  ProductError = 3 ,    ShippingError = null,  LogisticError =4},
                                                          new Farmers {ID = 8, Name = "Item8",  ProductError = null , ShippingError = 5,     LogisticError = 5}
                                                         };
          
            return farmers;
        }

    }


    public enum DropdownEnum
    {
        Production = 1,
        Shipping = 2,
        Logistics = 3,
    }

    public class Farmers
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Location
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public double? LogisticError
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int? ProductError 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int? ShippingError
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dwelling on it for few hours. Realize that need to extend the extended Where method that is on top of an IEnumerable to take a <condition,predicate>, which will solve the answer. Hence wrote a new extended method WhereIf.

```
 string dropdownSeletedValue = "0,1,2"; 
//this is also given where we can compare the string with the selected Value from the Dropdown. 
 public enum DropdownEnum:int
    {
        Production = 1,
        Shipping = 2,
        Logistics = 3,
    }
```

I can just use contains to satify the condition which is parameter 1 and pass my predicate as parameter 2.

```
        var retVal = farmerList.WhereIf(dropdownSeletedValue.Contains(((int)(DropdownEnum.Production)).ToString()), y => y.ProductError != null)
                               .WhereIf(dropdownSeletedValue.Contains(((int)(DropdownEnum.Shipping)).ToString()), y => y.ShippingError != null)
                               .WhereIf(dropdownSeletedValue.Contains(((int)(DropdownEnum.Logistics)).ToString()), y => y.LogisticError != null);
```

You might be asking where did I go the WhereIf on a list
This is how it is done.
Create a class as a helper method.

- 2nd one take <condition,predicate> which is used above built on top of IEnumerable keep that in mind.

```
public static class LinqHelper
        {
            public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
            {
                if (condition)
                return source.Where(predicate);
            else
                return source;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            if (condition)
                return source.Where(predicate);
            else
                return source;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
        {
            if (condition)
                return source.Where(predicate);
            else
                return source;
        }
    }

Your Welcome ! :)
```